# Can Period(.) be used in Domain Controller Name?

Tags: networking, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Is using Period(.) allowed in Domain Controller name?
If It is allowed, say Name of the DC is 'abc.def', How will the Distinguished Name be?
Option A. CN=abc,CN=def,CN=......
Option B. CN=abc.def,CN=....

Thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Distinguished Name for the Domain Controller, it should be CN=DomainContrller, DC=Contoso, DC=Com. You can get this information from **Properties** ->**Attribute Editor Tabl**-> **distinguishedname**

Or using ADSI edit and go to properties to get the DN
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a period in the computer name. Take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and for all the details.